# GUI App or Bash command to eliminate anything but official Ubuntu repository packages

Tags: command-line, bash, package-management, official-repositories

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS (64 bit Linux).

I want to know if there is some GUI App and/or a Bash command (command line) to full eliminate any package which is not from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Is there something like this?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from

Comment: ...and [Find local packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229887/986805)