# Where can I see how a program was installed?

Tags: apt, software-installation, synaptic

Is there a way to see whether any one application was installed via Snap, from a PPA, via downloaded deb or from a standard repository?

At the moment, I have Zoom installed on my Focal 20.04 laptop. I'm trying to figure out how I initially installed it, but I have this problem fairly often. Either it's a proprietary app (eg. Slack or Dropbox) and I want to update it, or the app is alerting me that a newer version is available (Keepass) and I want to doublecheck that I installed from a repository and can just wait for the repo to be updated.

If I had to guess, I'd say it's likely that I installed Zoom from a downloaded `.deb`, but I'm not sure how to check. I don't think I  installed Slack from a `.deb`.

I tried to follow some of the suggestions at [How do I find out which repository a package comes from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from) but the results are ambiguous. For instance there's no `apt policy` result for Slack:

```
amanda@rajje:~$ apt policy slack
slack:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:0.15.2-9
  Version table:
     1:0.15.2-9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Presumably because I installed it from Ubuntu Software, so it's a Snap:
[image: Screenshot of Slack entry]

If I try `apt policy` for an app that I know I haven't done any monkeying with I see a list of repositories. Can I assume that this means that I did install from a repository?

```
amanda@rajje:~$ apt policy emacs
emacs:
  Installed: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And if no repository is shown, does that mean that I installed from a package download?

```
amanda@rajje:~$ apt policy zoom
zoom:
  Installed: 5.0.403652.0509
  Candidate: 5.0.403652.0509
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.403652.0509 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which repository a package comes from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-find-out-which-repository-a-package-comes-from)

Comment: Start with `which` and `whereis`. Where is your Zoom executable located in your filesystem? Consider deleting your example, which confused me into thinking you were asking how to identify a Snap vs. deb. Your Zoom seems to be neither.

Comment: @user535733 I edited to clarify my question, which is broader than just "how is Zoom installed." It's definitely "how do I go about figuring out how any one thing was installed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with `which zoom` or `which zoom-client`. That will return the file-path to the executable. (Hint: <kbd>tab</kbd> completion is your friend)

Anything that starts with `/snap` was installed by Snap (Or the Ubuntu Software Center) so you can find out more by opening the software center or running `snap list | grep -i zoom` to get full/correct Snap name.

If it starts with `/usr/bin` it was probably installed with `apt` or Synaptic. In that case `dpkg -l | grep -i zoom` or `apt policy zoom*` will tell you more. Look at the "Installed (Local or Obsolete)" filter in Synaptic to see whether something installed by `apt` was local or via a repository.

You may also want to check for:

- Flatpak - check with `flatpak list | grep -i zoom`
- [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) - check with `umake --list-installed` (For example, IDEs)

Comment: This is very helpful. `which` hadn't occurred to me as a way to differentiate Snaps from things installed with `apt` / Synaptic. But `dpkg` doesn't show me whether I installed from a local file or a repository. I *think* `apt-cache policy` is telling me there's no repo associated with Zoom, so I can assume that was installed from a local package.

Comment: I couldn't believe I just *downloaded* zoom as a .deb file. I cancelled installation on reading this post and then it wouldn't *let* me install after that. All the while my version in the command line told me I hadn't updated: `ii  zoom                                       5.10.4.2845`. **Ubuntu Software** was saying I had 5.11. I had to uninstall before I could install to make it right. `dpkg -l`, and these heuristics, are a good answer. I like the question more as I didn't know about `apt policy` before.

Answer (score 2):

Install Synaptic Package Manager (you can install it from Ubuntu Software, or from command line using `sudo apt install synaptic`). It is a great tool to manage `.deb` packages. On the main screen, it shows you packages divided into groups, as you can see in the screenshot below. Look at group called "Installed (local or obsolete)" - these are packages that have been installed from manually downloaded files and not from repositories (some very essential system packages, like `libc`, are also included there). On my screenshot you can see `zoom` among those packages.

[image]

BTW. In your Slack example, the program is installed as snap, not a `.deb` package, which can be recognized by the presence of "Channel" at the beginning of the data on your screenshot. Snap packages always have a channel (usually `latest/stable`) while `.deb` packages don't. So neither `apt` nor Synaptic won't know anything about that package (in fact, in your example `apt policy` is showing you information about a **non-installed** `slack` package available to install as `.deb` from the repositories).

Comment: Hmm. So anything in "Installed (local or obsolete)" will be something I installed from a local file, rather than from a repository?

Comment: @Amanda As I wrote, some default system libraries are included in that category too. But otherwise yes. It may be also something you installed from a repository, but it's not available in repository anymore (that means "obsolete" in this context).

Answer (score -1):

This is way past the date that this was asked, but I quickly created a script (this morning) to search for apps in both repos and snap at the same time, and to query for an installed app with it's source.

If anyone finds it useful, here's the git repo:

https://github.com/rabinnh/uni-pkg-util/tree/main

Comment: Please include in the answer more details about your script - how to install it, how to use it, what the output looks like.